# Resolving a promise to multiple parameter values

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Is it possible to resolve a promise in such a way that the next promise in the chain can be an executor that takes multiple parameters?

For example, say I have a function that takes three parameters:

```
function takesThreeParameters (a, b, c) {
    console.log(`${a} ${b} ${c}`);
    return 'something';
}
```

If I'm including it in a chain, e.g. one of these:

```
// case 1: in a new Promise
new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve( /* ??? */ ))
    .then(takesThreeParameters)
    .then(console.log);

// case 2: in the middle of a chain somewhere
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => /* ??? */)
    .then(takesThreeParameters)
    .then(console.log);

// case 3: in the middle of a chain, but not as a function expression
function providesThreeValues () {
    return /* ??? */;
}
Promise.resolve()
    .then(providesThreeValues)
    .then(takesThreeParameters)
    .then(console.log);
```

Is there something I can return (in place of `/* ??? */`) in those cases (or at least in one of them) that will pass all three parameters in `.then(takesThreeParameters)`?

The important part of this question is if I can pass multiple parameters *directly* to an executor in a chain. So, strategies like these ones sort of bypass the question:

- Modifying `takesThreeParameters` to take a single parameter
- Resolving the previous promise with a dictionary then unpacking it (e.g. `abc => takesThreeParameters(abc.a, abc.b, abc.c)`)
- Same but with an array, etc. (`abc => takesThreeParameters(abc[0], abc[1], abc[2])`)

I.e. I'm looking for a way to make things like `.then((a, b, c) => /* code */)` work in a chain.

I tried some hand-wavey things that, unsurprisingly, didn't work, e.g. with case 1:

- `resolve(2,4,6)` results in: 2 undefined undefined, since resolve only takes one parameter.
- `resolve((2,4,6))` results in: 6 undefined undefined, as the value is a comma expression.
- `resolve([2,4,6])` results in: [2,4,6] undefined undefined, as expected.
- `resolve({2,4,6})` syntax error

I'm just using standard promises, whatever ships with Node.js v16.13.1 (which I think is ES6?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Promises spec only defines the *first* parameter. You can't pass in others, you can only emulate it using destructuring or spreads.

From the [Promises/A+ spec, 2.2.2.1](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-27), emphasis mine:

> If `onFulfilled` is a function:
>
> - it must be called after `promise` is fulfilled, **with `promise`’s value as its first argument**.

The ES6 spec describes this in [NewPromiseReactionJob (27.2.2.1) step 1.e](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-newpromisereactionjob):

> e. Else, let *handlerResult* be Completion(HostCallJobCallback(*handler*, **undefined**, « *argument* »)).

In both cases the spec allows *a single Promise handler value*. Unlike features like `setTimeout` where [additional arguments can be passed to the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#parameters), there is no such option for Promises.

You can at least avoid repeating the argument list with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
Promise.resolve()
    .then(providesThreeValues)
    .then(threeValues => takesThreeParameters(...threeValues))
    .then(console.log);
```

Likewise, if you are willing to edit the function, the edit to `takesThreeParameters` could be minimal with [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
function takesThreeParameters ([a, b, c]) {  // new brackets
    console.log(`${a} ${b} ${c}`);
    return 'something';
}
```

Comment: Appreciate you digging up the references. Also thanks for the parameter tips. I forgot about spread parameters and didn't even know about array destructuring. The spread syntax there is especially handy for maintenance if function signatures change.

Answer (score 4):

The `resolve` callback of `Promise` will just take the first parameter, so if you want to pass multiple values you need to pass an array, then you can read those values as individual params by destructuring:

```js
const takesThreeParameters = ([a, b, c]) => console.log(`a:${a} b:${b} c:${c}`)

const p = new Promise(res => setTimeout(res([1, 2, 3]), 2000))
p.then(takesThreeParameters)
```

EDIT: As per @Naor Tedgi 's answer, if you want to avoid to modify your existing functions, you can wrap them into an HOF:

```js
const wrap = (cb) => (args) => cb(...args)
const takesThreeParameters = (a, b, c) => console.log(`a:${a} b:${b} c:${c}`)
const wrappedFn = wrap(takesThreeParameters)

const p = new Promise(res => setTimeout(res([1, 2, 3]), 2000))
p.then(wrappedFn)
```

Comment: Passing either an array or an object as the single argument to `resolve()` is how you package multiple parameters in the single parameter and then you can optionally use destructuring to unpack either the object or the array.  So, this is a good example of one way to do it with an array.

Comment: Although the meat of my question was about passing parameters without modifying the function, I didn't know about array destructuring, thanks for that!

Comment: Yes I know Jason, but that can't be done unless you accept to wrap your functions in an HOF as per @Naor Tedgi 's answer .

Answer (score 1):

this hack should solve all use cases use the spreadParams function and resolve array

```
function spreadParams(cb) {
    return function (args) {
       return cb(...args)
    }
}

const takesThreeParameters = spreadParams((a, b, c) => {
    console.log(`${a} ${b} ${c}`);
    return 'something';
})

new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve([1, 2, 3]))
    .then(spreadParams(takesThreeParameters))
    .then(console.log);
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but you are applying the HOF twice, and you miss a return before `cb(...args)` if you want to keep chaining .then .

Comment: You right il update my answer

Comment: Nice idea thank you. You actually can use the original `takesThreeParameters`, you don't need the new definition you've got, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/gLwojeh0/1/). Also you can get `spreadParams` down to a one-liner if that's your thing, as `const spreadParams = cb => args => cb(...args);`.