# Is there promise resolve return more than one value

Tags: javascript, promise

```
function get(url) {
  console.log('Making fetch() request to: ' + url);

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url).then(response => {`enter code here`
      if (response.ok) {
        const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type') || '';

        if (contentType.includes('application/json')) {
          response.json().then(obj => {
            resolve(obj);
          }, error => {
            reject(new ResponseError('Invalid JSON: ' + error.message));
          });
        } else if (contentType.includes('text/html')) {
          response.text().then(html => {
            resolve({
              page_type: 'generic',
              html: html
            });
          }, error => {
            reject(new ResponseError('HTML error: ' + error.message));
          });
        } else {
          reject(new ResponseError('Invalid content type: ' + contentType));
        }
      } else {
        if (response.status == 404) {
          reject(new NotFoundError('Page not found: ' + url));
        } else {
          reject(new HttpError('HTTP error: ' + response.status));
        }
      }
    }, error => {
      reject(new NetworkError(error.message));
    });
  });

  return promise;
}
```

Comment: You can only resolve with a single value, but that value could be a container, e.g. an _array_ or _object_.

Comment: Ok, but how can i access multiple values using promise

Comment: Same comment again. You can only resolve (or reject) once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving a promise to multiple parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886910/resolving-a-promise-to-multiple-parameter-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const pobj = new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts1",function(data){
                resolve(data)
            }).fail((err)=>reject("Fail to load"))
        },1000)
    })

    async function abc(){
        const ob1= await pobj;
        ob1.forEach(element => {
            document.write(element.userId +"
")
        });
    }
    abc().catch((ERR)=>{document.write(ERR)});
    // pobj.then((res)=>{
    //     res.forEach(element => {
    //         document.write(element.title)
    //     });
    // }).catch((err)=> {
    //     document.write(err)
    // })

Comment: ITS work if we use resolve value to filter it outside promise block.